# How can I get a copy of my lost UK refusal letter in Nigeria

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens, lost-documents, nigeria

please how can I get a copy of my refusal from the UK embassy, I have sent In Mails and still haven’t heard from them.. should I go to the embassy? It is urgent.

Answer (score 1):

You can send a Subject Access Request to UKVI. This is a legal request for all the data the UKVI has on you, under the terms of the General Data Protection Regulation. There's a previous answer on here for how to do it with for the UK

[Subject Access Request - UK HOME OFFICE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143182/subject-access-request-uk-home-office)